# nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception, javabeans

I am currently working on a web Spring school project, and I ran into this exception and I can't find my way out of it.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

here's the link to the full project :

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-PgJ8PeUSdC4NhVVSK89xAbCM72ZB-bJ?usp=sharing

if someone can debug it and tell me where the problem is, that would be very helpful.

My thanks.

Comment: Avoid using this site as social media. Be specific about what you ask. Follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to know how to ask a question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can see what to run and where can the problem arise. Also, see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question on Stack Overflow. You haven't provided any code, nor you have provided any details on when the exception is thrown, what are the beans you have, what is the configuration file looking like, and etc. It's really difficult for us to answer the question which says nothing about the given scenario.

Comment: "if someone can debug it and tell me where the problem is, that would be very helpful"—that's not what we do here. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a application property, `spring.jpa.database-platform`. You should set it accordingly to the database you are using. E.g. `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`

P.S. This might not be the only property you are missing, you should add your application.properties file to see what other problems you might have.

Comment: i added the file application.properties under my src/main/resources folder and added the property you mentioned but still get the same exception.